# Django save data and send email at same time

Tags: postgresql, django-models, postman, sendmail

I want to why it is not saving message in database Postgres, but it is sending email well but data not saved in the database,

@require_POST
def send_contact(request):
    message_of_user = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf8'))

```
if isinstance(message_of_user, dict):
    message_of_user = [message_of_user]

try:

    for msg in message_of_user:
        message = Contact(**msg)
        message.save()
        from_email = message.email
        msg = message.name + ' Request' \
                             '' + ' for support in LEAP program with this Email.'
        send_mail('Student Request', msg, from_email, ['reciver@.com', ],
                  fail_silently=False, auth_user=None,
                  auth_password=None,
                  connection=None,
                  html_message=None)
    return JsonResponse({"Message": 'Contact_form send successfully'})

except Exception as error:
    return JsonResponse({'Message': 'Contact_form not sent', 'error': str(error)})
```

Comment: Perhaps because the code does not connect to nor send anything to the database. Please post the necessary database information including table definition and sample data and the sql you expect to store that data in the database.

Comment: Hey, Database stuff is working well because if I insert data only by removing send_mail function it saved data well. but if I run all above it do not save data but it send email